# How to force a parent element to keep size of its content on resize

Tags: html, css

I hope this one is solvable with CSS only. I have an element like this:

**HTML**

```
<a href="" title="">
    <img src="" alt=""/>
</a>
```

The height of the `<a>` element is set using percentage relative to the body's height. The image inside should always have 100% of the height of the `<a>` element. This works fine with a CSS like:

**CSS**

```
a {
    display: inline-block;
    height: 20%;
    margin: 0 5% 0 0;
    text-align: center;
}

a > img {
    height: 100%;
}
```

The problem I'm facing now is the following: When resizing the window, the image gets scaled correctly, as the `<a>`-element gets a correct new height. Unfortunately the `<a>`-element *keeps its initial width*. This means, that the margin gets useless and the elements start overlapping or drifting apart.

**The effect**

You can see the effect in this image:

[image]

**Demo**

[You can try it yourself](http://jsfiddle.net/Rjk8U/)

**Question**

Is there any way I can solve this in a way that the parent element has always the width of its content? When I reload the page with the new height after resizing, obviously everything fits again.

Comment: in chrome it doesn't scale the image correctly, it doesn't show red since the image is resizing incorrectly

Comment: @insertusernamehere take a look at this fiddle http://jsfiddle.net/Rjk8U/3/. Is what your looking for?

Comment: is there a particular reason why you need it to resize based on height and not width?

Comment: @Huangism Yeah, the page must always have 100% height - wide is flexible.

Answer (score 0):

Use div tag.
Create a separate division of your content.
Then you can customize all the things as much as you can.

Answer (score 0):

I solved it for the moment like this:

**CSS**

```
a {
    margin: 0 1% 0 0;
    background: red;
    text-align: center;
}

a > img {
    position: relative;
    height: 20%;
}
```

**Demo**

[Try it yourself](http://jsfiddle.net/yFUHZ/)

Comment: If somebody has another or better idea I would be grateful.

Answer (score 0):

You can do it with jquery

http://jsfiddle.net/Rjk8U/4/

```
$(window).on('resize', function() {
    $('a').css('width', $('img').width());
});
```

I am just setting the width of the anchor to the same as the width of the image. I could not figure out how to do it with only CSS

Note: I understand that you want the page to be 100% height but the blocks you have I assume is within the page, so why can't they be based on width percent instead? If you base it on height then when you only change the width of the page, the image does not resize